# How to use division in lm

Tags: r, lm

I would like to use `lm` to predict `y` by `a/b` (the quotient of a by b) when I do `lm(y~a/b)` I get `a` and `b` interactions, how can I do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`lm(y~I(a/b))`

This is covered in `?formula`.

Comment: `I(something)` tells R to evaluate that portion as a mathematical operation, rather than as formula command, e.g. `I(log(x))` takes the log of `x` and then fits a coefficient to the log of `x`.

Comment: @statquant  a:b is the same as seq(a,b,1) which is something completely  different

Comment: @lebatsnok Nope... that's the standard interpretation of `a:b`, but inside of a formula (as in `lm`), that specifies the interaction of `a` and `b`. `a/b`, when not inside `I()`, specifies `a` and its interaction with `b`, but no term for the effect of `b` alone.

Comment: Whenever I get confused about this stuff, I just set up some random data to test it. Try something like `y <- rnorm(100); a <- rnorm(100); b <- rnorm(100); summary(lm(y ~ a +b)); summary(lm(y ~ a * b)); summary(lm(y ~ a/b)); summary(lm(y ~ I(a/b)))` - comparing the summaries will quickly give you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: And comparing plots of the values of `a` and/or `b` to model predictions of `y` can be helpful, too.